# LocalStorage array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Guys help me with this code. The idea is to save new inputs in a string and display them using HTML. Every time I add a new one the HTML displays it, if I reload the page the items are still displayed and the first `getItem` method and if I reload again is still working but here is the problem. After I reload the page and I insert a new element in string then it will display the just the lates inputs and will delete the ones from other sessions.

If I insert now :"one","two","three" it I will display "one,two,three" if I reload it will still display " one,two,three" which is good, but after the reload if I insert "four" it will display only "four" and I want to be displayed "one,two,three,four".

How can I make this happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button onclick="reloadd()">Reload</button>
    <button onclick="clearF()">Clear</button>
    <input id="valoare">
    <button id="adauga" onclick="adauga()">+</button>
    <button onclick="nrElemente()">ElemNr?</button>
    <script>
      var cars = [];
      var two = "kes";

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("array1");

      function clearF() {
        window.localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
      }

      function adauga() {
        var x = document.getElementById('valoare').value;
        cars.push(x);

        localStorage.setItem("array1", cars);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("array1");
      }

      function reloadd() {
        location.reload();
      }

      function nrElemente() {
        alert(localStorage.length);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are not storing your array **anywhere**.
To save your array into `localStorage` you would use:

```
localStorage.setItem("cars", JSON.stringify(cars));
```

Then instead of doing this:

```
var cars = [];
```

You would load your cars array like this:

```
var cars = localStorage.getItem("cars");
cars = (cars) ? JSON.parse(cars) : [];
```

What this is doing is, it is checking if the `localStorage` object contains an `array` called `cars`. Now if it does it will parse that string and return the stored cars array, if it does not it will set the cars array to a new empty array.

Here, I have fixed and tidied your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <button onclick="reloadd()">Reload</button>
  <button onclick="clearF()">Clear</button>
  <input id="valoare" />
  <button id="adauga" onclick="adauga()">+</button>
  <button onclick="nrElemente()">ElemNr?</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var array1 = localStorage.getItem("array1");
    array1 = (array1) ? JSON.parse(array1) : [];

    var two = "kes";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("array1");

    function clearF() {
      window.localStorage.clear();
      location.reload();
    }
    function adauga() {
      var x = document.getElementById("valoare").value;
      array1.push(x);
      localStorage.setItem("array1", JSON.stringify(array1));
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("array1");
    }
    function reloadd() {
      location.reload();
    }
    function nrElemente() {
      alert(localStorage.length);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, it's considered bad practice to place your JavaScript events & functions in HTML attributes. Try to separate HTML, CSS & JS as much as possible by placing **all** (or at-least most) of your JS in your script element / JS file.

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: guys please test your code because your support may be useful and correct but in my code have no effect like ..I changed the localStorage.setItem after you said and var cars with your code too and the code just does not do anything

Comment: Yep that is thanks it work ..but how can I delete the square brakets?

Comment: You don't  those *"represent"* your array. Those *"square brackets"* show up when you use `console.log();` or `alert();`. If you would like to turn your JSON string into a JavaScript Object use `JSON.parse();`. If my answer has helped you don't forget to up-vote and accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an empty array every page load and when you add to array you store that but never connect `cars` array to the data that is already stored

Try changing

```
var cars =[];
```

To

```
var localData = localStorage.getItem("array1");
// if localData not undefined then parse that as cars array, otherwise is empty array
var cars = localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
```

When you go to store the `cars` array change to:

```
localStorage.setItem("array1",JSON.stringify(cars));
```

Comment: well this is a very common pattern...try logging `cars` to console

Comment: guys can you please give me a cod which does what I wanted to achieve first time please?to save the inputs and don t lose them

Comment: ooo   note you should use `JSON.stringify()` also when you set the localStorage...localStorage only stores strings. If you are fighting with it you can use `store.js` library

Comment: those 2 changes should do it... are you not seeing the full array in console now?

Comment: I am using browser to see the results and right now I use the platform from w3schools             http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Answer (score 0):

There were some major issues with your code, this is a fixed version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cars = [];
  try {
    cars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array1"));
  } catch (err) {}

  var two = "kes";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cars;

  function clearF() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
  }
  function adauga() {
    var x = document.getElementById('valoare').value;
    cars.push(x);
    localStorage.setItem("array1", JSON.stringify(cars));
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("array1");
  }
  function reloadd() {
    location.reload();
  }
  function nrElemente() {
    alert(localStorage.length);
  }
</script>
```